# ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers' returned a non-zero code: 3

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i just follow the demo of docker-compose official documentation

virtual machine: VMware Workstation 15 Player
OS: Centos7

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
 services:
   web:
       build: .
       ports:
        - "5000:5000"
   redis:
       image: "redis:alpine"
```

Dockerfile:

```
ROM python:3.7-alpine
WORKDIR /code
ENV FLASK_APP app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

run commend:

```
docker-compose up
```

log and error message

```
Building web
Step 1/9 : FROM python:3.7-alpine
 ---> 7fbc871584eb
Step 2/9 : WORKDIR /code
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c20780a4b2d4
Step 3/9 : ENV FLASK_APP app.py
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 973cc407ca91
Step 4/9 : ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 23891144700d
Step 5/9 : RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
 ---> [Warning] IPv4 forwarding is disabled. Networking will not work.
 ---> Running in 7b29f4df9539
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
WARNING: Ignoring http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz: temporary error (try again later)
WARNING: Ignoring http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz: temporary error (try again later)
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  gcc (missing):
    required by: world[gcc]
  linux-headers (missing):
    required by: world[linux-headers]
  musl-dev (missing):
    required by: world[musl-dev]
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers' returned a non-zero code: 3
```

who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of the error that you get is that GCC is not installed (failed to install) on the docker image. Make sure that you have internet connection to install these libs.

from the warning that you have

```
---> [Warning] IPv4 forwarding is disabled. Networking will not work.
```

it seems that Docker containers do not have an internet connection, you must enable the `IPv4 forwarding` using the following commands

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

more info can be found [here](http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/01/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-in-linux/)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem on fedora by partialy using blog from: https://fedoramagazine.org/docker-and-fedora-32/

Enable old CGroups:

```
sudo grubby --update-kernel=ALL --args="systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"
```

Whitelist docker in firewall:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-interface=docker0
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=FedoraWorkstation --add-masquerade
```

Install dependencies for docket-composer:

```
sudo dnf install python3-attrs python3-bcrypt python3-cached_property python3-docker python3-docker-pycreds python3-dockerpty python3-docopt python3-fluidity-sm python3-invoke python3-jsonschema python3-lexicon python3-paramiko python3-pyasn1 python3-pynacl python3-pyrsistent python3-texttable python3-websocket-client
```

```
sudo reboot
```